# Warning: mysqli_stmt:: execute() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in

Tags: php, mysqli

When I post HTML form I am trying to print it to database. It gives the error I mentioned in the title. I couldn't understand because I don't have much knowledge. There is a table named "users" in the database. This table has 4 values. Username, usertag, userphone, name.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "formusers";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if ($_POST) {
    if ($_POST['submitForm'] == "formSave") {
        $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST["username"]);
        $usertag = htmlspecialchars($_POST["usertag"]);
        $userphone = htmlspecialchars($_POST["userphone"]);
        $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]);
        if ($usertag !== '') {
            $hextech = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?);");
            $hextech->execute([$username, $usertag, $userphone, $name]);

            if ($hextech) {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-success">
                                                        <p>Thanks.</p>
                                                        </div>';
                //form
            } else {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                                                <p>Some problems.</p>
                                                </div>';
                //form
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Required';
        }
    }
}
```